# Using microcontroller's ADC to measure the voltage between LiPo cells

Tags: microcontroller, lithium-ion

What I want to do is to measure the balancer output of a 3 cell LiPo, and if any cell drops lower than 3V I want to put my uC in the shutdown mode. Gonna be using STM32F401RET6.

First question is: is it actually a good idea to do it this way, or should i do it externally (not in uC), using a couple of op-amps.

And secondly, what kind of socket do I need to plug the balance connector to my pcb. Dualsky is my Li-Po manufacturer.

Comment: Think about it for a minute - how many of the taps will be within the MCU ADC's input voltage range?   As for identifying the connector, that is off topic here, especially with nothing but the name of a manufacturer, who no doubt offers more than one battery pack.  Try a radio control forum for that.

Comment: If I were to do this, I might be inclined to use an instrumentation amplifier across each cell (that way you get a voltage proportional to cell voltage from each amplifier); how you do the measurement bwyond that is open to question.

Comment: These amps are not that cheap (couple dollars per 1), and i need 3 of them. Wouldnt it be equally good to just implement a voltage divider to squash the voltage from 11,1V to 3,3V? Something like 20k resistor between last balance pin (11,1V) and uC ADC pin, and from that pin to ground through a 10k resistor.

Comment: Depends if you can find a compromise between resistor values large enough to not drain the cell more than you are comfortable with (especially after you shut it down) but small enough for the loading of the ADC input to be insignificant.  That's math you can do, somewhat dependent on the capacity for the cells which you haven't stated.  IIRC STM32 ADC input impedance depends on clock rate, so you will probably want to run it slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a valid approach, certainly with just three cells. You have three voltages to measure. Obviously you'll need a voltage divider on at least two of them and you'll have to consider the current draw of the divider keeping in mind that the micro probably wants to see 10K or less looking out of the ADC inputs. It's also possible to use a higher resistance dividers (M\$\Omega\$) and buffer the outputs with some inexpensive CMOS-input op-amps, or to switch the divider when you want a measurement with a high-side MOSFET or BJT switch.

You'll have to watch the divider tolerances vs. the shut-down tolerance you're trying to achieve. If you use 1% tolerance resistors the error due to resistor tolerances alone could be much higher than 1% even though each measurement is only affected by ~1% by resistor tolerances (depending on the exact ratio- worst-case error of a voltage divider made from 1% resistors is between 1% for equal resistors to about 2% for very unequal resistors). Consider this example with 100K/200K nominal resistors.

```
VM2 is 2.970V -1.00% error

VM3 is 3.040V  +1.33% error
```

Your calculation for the top cell would be V3 = VM3*3-VM2*2. In this case the error as a percentage of V3 is **+6%** even though all the resistors are within tolerance. You can always consider 0.1% resistors and it's unlikely (but possible) that the resistors would be so perversely off tolerance in the worst directions.

This rapidly becomes a losing approach as the number of cells increases though.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4caO0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I guess I wanna look at the "external imput impedance" in the table "ADC characteristics", is that correct? So according to the datasheet max external input impedance is 50 kΩ.
So I assume it's safe to use 5x20k 0.1% resistors in my divider.

Comment: If the resistors are R the impedance the ADC sees is (1/2)R for the first divider and (2/3) R for the second. Using the same value with one doubled up is a good approach.

Comment: Why exactly is that? I got the general feeling its going to be like this, but maybe you could elaborate a bit.

Comment: Assuming you mean the calculation- the resistors are effectively in parallel when connected to a 'stiff' voltage source- the top of the divider can be consider as connected to ground through an ideal source so any current coming in or out of the ADC sees both resistors in parallel.

Comment: I dont quite understand, between which two points is this resistance measured.

Comment: Between the divider output and ground.